# Could Reactive Extension capture/detect consecutive cases?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Use this, Rx generates a series of random numbers between 0 and 99.

```
var R = new Random();
var ints = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var RandomNos = ints.Select(i=> R.Next(100)); // was new Random().Next(100) 
RandomNos.Subscribe(r=> Console.Write(r+ ","));
```

---

```
1,75,49,23,97,71,45,19,93,66,40,14,88,62,36,10,84
```

---

I want to capture/detect when I get 6 more-than-50 numbers in a row. Can Rx do it?

```
RandomNos.?????()
.Subscribe(l=> Console.WriteLine ("You got 6 more-than-50 numbers in a row"));
```

Comment: You should not be constantly creating new `Random` instances.  Instead create one and call `Next` on it repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is with the [`Buffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228968(v=vs.103).aspx) method.

```
var random = new Random();
var result = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Select(i => random.Next(100))
    .Buffer(6, 1)
    .Where(buffer => buffer.All(n => n > 50))
```

If instead of 6-in-a-row you were trying to detect `K`-in-a-row, where K was really really huge, then you'd probably want to do something using `Window` instead, but since K = 6 here it's easiest to just do what I suggested.

Also, be aware that the probability of a number drawn uniformly from {0, 1, ..., 99} being greater than 50 is 49/100, not 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's one that only uses a single counter for any "n" in a row - it keeps a running count of numbers over 50 - the `Take(1)` completes the stream at the first occurrence.

```
RandomNos.Scan(0, (a,x) => x > 50 ? ++a : 0)
         .Where(x => x == 6)
         .Take(1)
         .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("You got 6 more-than-50 numbers in a row"));
```

Comment: Note that Tim's answer is O(1) in memory too.

Comment: Tim's answer is also O(1) in that respect.

Comment: He needs a buffer of size [0,6].  That's O(1), because the size of the buffer is always less than a constant amount (6).

Comment: I think I already admitted I was wrong about the O(n)... I am focussing on the fact that for say, 1 million in a row, I have a single counter, whereas he needs a million buffers. You also missed the fact there are multiple buffers.... really the -1 is a bit harsh.

Comment: But the question doesn't require a million consecutive items, it requires 6, set as a constant.

Comment: You are right Servy... well done. Silly me for suggesting an interesting aside along with an alternative answer. Especially one addressing a point that Tim brought up himself!

Comment: You haven't suggested a corollary.  Your proposal does not follow from what is already proven.

Comment: Well, hopefully someone else will find this of interest! :) Tell you what, I'll leave it here just in case.

Comment: Your answer is interesting & helpful.

Comment: @JamesWorld - Very nice use of `Scan`. That's one useful operator - very good at introducing "local" state.